# How to get parameter from previous template into current template's helper method

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am using Meteor + FlowRouters.

Suppose I have 2 pages **Products** and **payments**. User selects the product(we store "_id" as hidden field) from **Products** page and redirects to **Payments**.

**Scenario:**

Product Page(**_id as 'queryparam'**) **--------->** Payments Page (**how to grab _id in helper here?**)

**Question:**

Here at Payments page, I want to show the product details from "_id" we passed from Product page, as a checkout information. I want to grab the parameter in my helper methods of **Payments**, how to do that?

Comment: What routing mechanism do you use? You can send the id as one of the optional/mandatory parameters in the URL if you're using iron router..

Comment: I am using Flow routing.

Comment: There should be something similar to that in flow router also. Let me take a quick look

Comment: I am passing queryParam from previous template helper. I just want the same parameter somehow in current template helper.

Comment: What does ```this.data.params()``` give?

Comment: lol where should I call this? on template or helper?

Comment: Sorry. In your payments helper, if you execute ```this.data.params()```, does it contain the ```_id``` field that you'd initially passed from the product page?

Comment: let me check quickly and see. By the way is there this.data.queryParams() as well?

Comment: @blueren : When I did console.log(this) in template helper, it gave me this : Object { main: _buildRegionGetter/<(), data: _buildRegionGetter/<() }

Comment: Please, read the doc, it is perfectly explained there https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router#flowroutergetparamparamname

Comment: @Artūrs Lataks you are right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my payments page

Payments.html

```
<template name="App_Payments">
  <div>
    {{id}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Payments.js

```
import './Payments.html';

Template.App_Payments.helpers({
      id() {
       // below "id" is passed from Products page.
        return  FlowRouter.getQueryParam("id");
      }
});
```